# How to change background colour of the mini variant drawer?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tried changing the colour using one of their methods such as

```
V1
<Drawer style={{backgroundColour: black}} variant="permanent" open={open} >

V2
<Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}
      backgroundColor="black">
```

But it just won't change in the drawer, nothing happens, I've looked at documentation and it doesn't clearly tell me what to do for it. I'm quite new to react.

[Mini Variant Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysEiW.png)

[Mini Variant Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgXTz.png)

Was trying to change this drawer to black

Comment: try adding a `!important` to the style

Comment: No idea what that is sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, just try to use `PaperProps`, hope is would solve the issue:

```
    <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}
        PaperProps={{
            style: {
            backgroundColor: "black",
            },
        }}
     >
```